# Does curl -k work also with expired certificates?

Tags: ssl, curl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm using a self-signed certificate in a private network that will expire after several days. I need a certificate just to exploit its keys to set up https connections. Therefore, a self-signed is enough in my case.

I'm already using `curl -k https://mylocal.url.local` to overcome problems about the signature. I'm wondering if it will still work also **after the expiration date**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use of `-k` also prevents checking the validity of a certificate as can be seen here:

[image]

As you can see this used curl on Windows (10 in this case), but I receive similar output on Ubuntu and - what is even more important - the same reaction when `-k` is added:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

As far as your side question is concerned: with all these browsers I was able to ignore the warning about the expired certificate:

- Firefox 91 (ESR)
- Chrome 96
- Microsoft Edge 94
- Microsoft Internet Explorer contained in Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2

My installation of Postman ignored the expired certificate from the beginning. I don't remember if this was an installation default or if I changed it to `off` a long time ago:

[image]

Comment: Side question: does the same happen also with browsers when you click on "Proceed to https://... (unsafe)" or postman? I mean, can you always start a HTTPS connection with an expired cert?

Comment: @floatingpurr please see my update